# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens entre Apache e nginx?

Tags: apache, nginx

Vejo muita gente recomendando o nginx sobre o Apache [HTTP Server], e posso entender bem como por o primeiro ser *event-driven* ele traz vantagens quanto à escalabilidade (i.e. baixo consumo de memória sob carga pesada) em relação à abordagem *process-based* do segundo. Mas não estou certo quanto às suas desvantagens, ou casos em que o Apache seria uma solução melhor. Citando por exemplo [esse site](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/apache_vs_nginx) (que fala muito do nginx mas quase nada do Apache):

> O Apache é como o Microsoft Word, ele tem um milhão de opções mas você só precisa de seis. O nginx faz essas seis coisas, e cinco delas 50 vezes mais rápido que o Apache.

Que situações então seria o Apache a melhor solução? Ou: quais os principais pontos de diferença entre eles, que podem ser chave para a escolha entre um e outro numa determinada situação?

Answer (score 11):

Acredito que a experiência no uso de cada um destes servidores é fundamental.

Qualquer um deles pode ser facilmente "atolado" de *addons* e logo perder desempenho, como também, especialmente o Apache, pode ser limpo e possuir alto desempenho.

Eu trabalho há anos com Apache e não o troco. Tenho servidores com finalidades diferentes e alcancei desempenho semelhante aos divulgados pelo nginx, e ainda mantendo os anos de experiência e longe do vazamento de abstração.

Bom, minha sugestão é: Os dois são bons, logo, se você não tem experiência em nenhum deles, pode escolher qualquer um, e inclusive me parece ser uma melhor opção o nginx, porém, não aconselho trocar um pelo outro, apenas por indicadores de desempenho divulgados pelos evangelistas, afinal, problemas como o [*C10k problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) já foram solucionados há tempos pelo Apache mas ainda são usados como argumento nas palestras sobre nginx.

Estou no time que acha que "*Panela véia é que faz comida boa*" :D

Mas, vamos aos números:

[image: Grafico de desempenho 1]

[image: Grafico de desempenho 2]

Para entrega de arquivos menores, o Nginx tem melhor desempenho em alto volume de requisições, já o processamento do PHP fica melhor no Apache 2.4

Fonte das imagens:
http://blog.corujadeti.com.br/nova-versao-do-apache-2-4-2-versus-nginx-fight/

Comment: Sinto falta de uma explicação sobre *"quais os principais pontos de diferença entre eles [...]"*, tal como solicitado na pergunta...

Comment: Se você avaliar reviews sempre encontrará os itens "Desempenho", "Segurança" e "Escala" como diferencial. Veja um exemplo: http://blog.corujadeti.com.br/nova-versao-do-apache-2-4-2-versus-nginx-fight/

Comment: Queria dizer que sinto falta no contexto deste site, sem precisar ir a outro site pra aprender uma coisa nova, mas obrigado pela referência ;)

Comment: Veja a edição com a inclusão dos números

Comment: Esse gráfico com as requisições/segundo com PHP não dizem se foi utilizado mod_php ou FastCGI. Isso não deve ser levado em consideração? Se não, porque?

Comment: Sim, deve ser levado em consideração se você optar por utilizar o PHP após este estudo de desempenho. Mas estes detalhes você pode questionar no blog Coruja de TI que executou os testes, ok? Um abraço!